# how to find num of 00:01 in time() fun php?

Tags: php, date, time

The time () function in php outputs the number of the current server.
Now I want to get the number at 00:01 today and yesterday.

Ex:
Time() : outputs the number of the current server OR
time()-(1*24*60*60) : outputs the number of the yesterday.

But I want these numbers today and yesterday at 00:01.

How?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: He wants to output `2017-07-29 00:01` and `2017-07-28 00:01` I think

Comment: explain your question , with your code.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns the number of seconds passed since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (aka the Unix Epoch). It doesn't matter on what server the script runs, it doesn't matter the timezone of the server or the default timezone used by PHP, as long as the server's clock shows the correct time, the `time()` function returns the same value.

PHP provides a lot of [functions to handle date & time](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php). Take a look at them then forget about most of them; you don't need them. Those whose name starts with `date_` are just aliases of methods of the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class (and its friends), the others are old and do not handle multiple timezones.

There are only several date/time functions you should remember: [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) (to get a timestamp), [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to learn how to format a date and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to learn about the input formats recognized by the functions that create `DateTime` objects.

> Now I want to get the number at 00:01 today and yesterday.

I guess `00:01` is one minute after the midnight. It's easy to create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object that encapsulates the moment in time when it was `00:01` today:

```
$today = new DateTime('00:01');
```

The first argument of [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) is a [string representation of the date](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) to create. If the date is not complete, the missing date components are initialized with today's date and the missing time components are initialized with `0`.

There are several ways to create a `DateTime` object for "yesterday at 00:01". The easiest one is to just express it in the string passed to the constructor:

```
$yesterday = new DateTime('yesterday 00:01');
```

Another option is to create it the same as `$today` and the [subtract](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) one day from it:

```
$yesterday = new DateTime('00:01');
$yesterday->modify("-1 day");
```

Let's see what we get:

```
echo('Today    : '.$today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e'));
echo('Yesterday: '.$yesterday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e'));
```

It prints:

```
Today    : 2017-07-29 00:01:00 Europe/Bucharest
Yesterday: 2017-07-28 00:01:00 Europe/Bucharest
```

It probably prints a different timezone for you. This is because the string passed as first argument doesn't contain a timezone and I didn't pass a second argument to [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php). In this case, PHP uses the default timezone (set in `php.ini` or using the [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function).

To make sure the code works the same on all servers, either pass a [`DateTimeZone`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) object as the second argument to [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) or use the function [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the default time zone when the script starts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:.

```
Echo date("Y-m-d ") . "00:01\n";
Echo date("Y-m-d ", strtotime("yesterday")) . "00:01";
```

Strtotime can read simple strings and convert to a plus or minus time.
https://3v4l.org/bLOq3

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas has a good approach but the appended string '00:01' makes it not suitable as the OP wants the timestamp, i.e. _integer representation. Also, `strtotime()` understands more than single words. First, set time zone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

This gets those two timestamps

```
strtotime('yesterday midnight')
strtotime('yesterday midnight') + 1
```

This prints formatted date string to compare to:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('yesterday midnight') + 1); // 2017-07-28 00:00:01
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('today midnight') + 1); // 2017-07-29 00:00:01
```

Comment: I don't see that op wants a UNIX value. But if that is the case my answer can easily be modified to suit. Also I didn't say strtotime only understand single words.